# Forward custom allocator in std::vector to a class element

Tags: c++, vector, allocator

Is there a possibility to forward a custom allocator in std::vector to a class element? Assume there is a declaration `std::vector<Foo>` and Foo is a class which also needs an allocator. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you mean a stateful allocator, The vector doesn't have any mechanism to pass the instance of the allocator to the children, so you need to have some sort of "root" allocator outside both classes, and pass "children" allocators to both the vector and also each element.

Comment: @MooingDuck There's [`std::scoped_allocator_adapter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor). Never used it, but it should work.

Comment: You'd have to utilise C++17 `std::pmr` implementation of vector.

Comment: The [std::scoped_allocator_adapter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor) is a good hint.